# substring starting with a char and following with digits in java

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

How can I get the substring start with "$r" char following with digits and continue until the last digit. For example for the following strings I want these outputs:

example1: "helloeveryone$r123Stack(overflow24)" -> output:$r123

example2: "dskjlu h5678kjjklds($r34563478jlsd)sdjks%6jkj" -> output:$r34563478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression with `String.replaceAll(String, String)` on a literal `$r` followed by one or more digits. Something like,

```
String[] arr = { "helloeveryone$r123Stack(overflow24)", 
        "dskjlu h5678kjjklds($r34563478jlsd)sdjks%6jkj" };
for (String str : arr) {
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*(\\$r\\d+).*", "$1"));
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
$r123
$r34563478
```